# List all commands of a specific Debian package

Tags: debian, ubuntu, command-line

I want to know the commands that a specific Debian package offers me.

For example lets say I installed a package called `x.deb`. This package surely contains some commands that i can use.

How to list these commands.

I know I can use `compgen` bash command to generate list of all available commands in my system but what i need is just for specific package.

I tried the solutions:

```
dpkg -L postgresql-9.3 | egrep '(bin|games)/'
/usr/lib/postgresql/9.3/bin/pg_upgrade
/usr/lib/postgresql/9.3/bin/pg_ctl
/usr/lib/postgresql/9.3/bin/pg_resetxlog
/usr/lib/postgresql/9.3/bin/postgres
/usr/lib/postgresql/9.3/bin/pg_xlogdump
/usr/lib/postgresql/9.3/bin/initdb
/usr/lib/postgresql/9.3/bin/pg_controldata
/usr/lib/postgresql/9.3/bin/postmaster
```

I tried the command `postgres`

```
user@userPc:~$ postgres
No command 'postgres' found, did you mean:
 Command 'postgrey' from package 'postgrey' (universe)
postgres: command not found
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use `dpkg -L pkgname` and pipe it to a grep command searching for `bin/` and `games/`:

```
$ dpkg -L bash | grep -E '/(s?bin|games)/'
/bin/bash
/usr/bin/bashbug
/usr/bin/clear_console
/bin/rbash
```

If you want to check for all binaries regardless if they are in your `$PATH` try this bash function:

```
find_binaries (){
    dpkg -L "$@" | while read -r; do
        [ -f "$REPLY" -a -x "$REPLY" ] && echo "$REPLY"
    done
}
```

Invoke like so:

```
$ find_binaries postfix
...SNIP...
/usr/lib/postfix/postfix-files
/usr/lib/postfix/pipe
/usr/lib/postfix/proxymap
/usr/lib/postfix/local
/usr/lib/postfix/discard
...SNIP...
```

Comment: There could be bin outside bin/ or games/.

Comment: dpkg -L apache2 | egrep '(bin|games)/'  No result. Please improve your answer

Comment: @Hadi `apache2` may be a bad example because that package is a metapackage that usually isn't even installed on systems running Apache. The command works - try `coreutils`: `dpkg -L coreutils | egrep '(bin|games)/'`

Comment: I tried for postgres check the edit

Comment: @Hadi check out my latest edit.

Comment: +1, very nice. Just a couple of comments, you might want to use `grep -Ew 'bin|sbin|games'` instead, egrep is deprecated and you may as well search for sbin as well. Also, there is no reason to use a `for` loop here, using a `while` loop as I did in my answer instead, means you don't need to worry about IFS and word splitting.

Comment: Hi @terdon thank you for the suggestions! Do you know where `egrep` has been marked as deprecated? I updated my answer to use `grep` though I kept the regex the same as it matches `sbin`, `bin`, and `games` while not matching strings that are not part of directories in one's path like `/usr/share/games/`. I also updated my answer to use `while read` instead. Much cleaner!

Comment: From `man grep`: `Direct  invocation  as  either egrep  or  fgrep  is  deprecated,  but  is provided to allow historical applications that rely on them to run unmodified.` Also, you regex, will match _any_ directory that contains either `games` or `bin` which will include `/usr/share/games/`, and also `foosbinaff` and whatever else.

Comment: @Hadi Executables that are outside the directories in the default PATH (`/bin`, `/usr/bin`, `/sbin`, `/usr/sbin` and `/usr/games`) are not commands meant to be executed by users, so they should be excluded from the output here.

Answer (score 13):

#### 1. Use a tool designed for the job.

The easiest and probably the most robust way is to install `dlocate`:

```
sudo apt-get install dlocate
```

You can then run

```
dlocate -lsbin package-name
```

As explained in `man dlocate`:

```
-lsbin List full path/filenames of executable files (if any) in package
```

#### 2. Parse the package database

This is a similar approach to @Winny's but simplified

```
apt-file -F list package | cut -d ' ' -f 2 | 
    while read file; do [[ -x $file && -f $file ]] && echo "$file"; done
```

If you don't have `apt-file` installed, you can install and set it up with these commands:

```
sudo apt-get install apt-file
sudo apt-file update
```

The command above uses `apt-file` to list a package's contents and then bash's tests `-f` (is this a file?) and `-x` (is it executable?) and prints the file's name if both tests are passed.

Note that while something like the command below will get you *most* executables:

```
apt-file -L list package | grep -Ew 'bin|sbin'
```

it will not find all because you also get executables in places like `/opt` or even `/lib` (various `udev` tools for example). So, while using the `-w` to match whole words increases your chances of identifying the files correctly, parsing the path is not a good approach and you should use one of the methods above instead.

Comment: Executables in `/opt` or `/lib` are not meant to be invoked by users, so you shouldn't list them. `apt-file -F list $package | grep -E '^(/usr)/(s?bin|games)/' gives you the list, with one exception: [alternatives](http://askubuntu.com/questions/436278/how-do-i-list-commands-a-package-provides/436332#436332).

Comment: @Gilles I don't see why not, the OP asked for commands, whether these were meant to be run manually or not is besides the point. Also, there are perfectly good reasons to use some of them, for example `/lib/udev/findkeyboards` can be very useful when [writing keyboard udev rules](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/88801/22222).

Comment: `/lib/udev/rule_generator.functions` can be useful too. If you start listing everything that's useful, then it's not just executables you need to list, but any kind of code library.

Answer (score 3):

If you have `dlocate` installed, [there's an easy way](https://askubuntu.com/questions/435168/how-can-i-know-what-programs-does-some-apt-get-package-contains/435176#435176) to list all the commands in an installed package:

```
dlocate -lsbin PACKAGE-NAME
```

With just `dpkg`, you can list the files in the standard PATH directories (they're almost all executable programs, with very few exceptions):

```
dpkg -L PACKAGE-NAME… | sed -n 's!^\(/s\?bin\|/usr/s\?bin\|/usr/games\)/!!p' | sort -u
```

The exceptions are a couple directories — as of Debian wheezy, just two: `/usr/bin/mh` and `/usr/bin/nu-mh`.

If the package isn't installed, replace `dpkg -L` by `apt-file -F list`:

```
apt-file -F list PACKAGE-NAME… | sed -n 's!^\(/s\?bin\|/usr/s\?bin\|/usr/games\)/!!p' | sort -u
```

While there are executable files in other directories, they are not meant to be executed directly, which makes them irrelevant here.

These methods all miss a set of programs: those that are provided through the [alternatives](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianAlternatives) mechanism. For example, for the [`ftp`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/ftp) package, only `netkit-ftp` and `pftp` are provided, but this package actually provides the `ftp` command, because `/usr/bin/ftp` is a symbolic link to `/etc/alternatives/ftp` which is a symbolic link to one of the `ftp` implementations on the system, potentially `/usr/bin/netkit-ftp`. The following command (which isn't an example of good programming, just a big one-liner) lists the commands provided by a package via the alternatives mechanism, as currently configured.

```
perl -lwe 'foreach (`dpkg -L @ARGV`) {chomp; ++$p{$_}} foreach (</bin/* /sbin/* /usr/bin/* /usr/sbin/*>) {$e = readlink; next unless defined $e and $e =~ m!^/etc/alternatives/!; $t = readlink $e; print if $p{$t}}' PACKAGE_NAME…
```

If you want to list the commands that could be provided via an alternative which is currently configured to point to a different package, you need to parse the files in `/var/lib/dpkg/alternatives`.

Symbolic links and configuration files that implement the alternatives mechanisms are not registered in packages but registered automatically in `postinst`, which makes it difficult (and in fact technically impossible if a package's installation script doesn't follow conventions) to query the alternatives provided by an uninstalled package.

Answer (score 0):

1. Normally, *bin/ are the most common places to have all programs placed. Even using a link. So there is very little chance that you need to concern commands outside *bin/.
2. If you have not installed apache2, `dpkg -L` surely won't give you result. Please try apt-file tool (you need to install it).
3. The name apache2 is a metapackage, it does not contain any programs.

Answer (score -1):

use below one command and replace systemd with your targeted package name. this command will list all available commands with their one-liner intro respectively

```
dpkg -L systemd | grep 'sbin\|bin' | awk -F "/" '{print $NF}' | xargs man | grep ' - ' 2> /dev/null
```