# How to list all commands contained in a specific rpm package?

Tags: yum, rpm

I found this exact question *for Debian* here: [List all commands of a specific Debian package](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/122524/list-all-commands-of-a-specific-debian-package)

But it seems no one has ever asked this for RHEL/CentOS (or OpenSUSE for that matter).

For instance, I can run `rpm -qf $(which dig)` to find out that `dig` comes from the `bind-utils` package.  I can run `yum -C info bind-utils` to quickly see the data on that package...but how can I see what other commands are included in the `bind-utils` package?

Ideally the solution should be independent of my `$PATH` variable, as even with a broken path or a non-system user path (e.g. not including `/sbin`), I might simply want to know what commands were installed from a given package.

Comment: Someone else will have something better, but here's something quick & dirty: `rpm -ql $package | grep bin/` -- which simply lists the files in the package and greps for a binary path (sbin or bin).

Comment: Yep, and yours is simpler than mine.  Mine handles the small edge case of executable files being included elsewhere than bin directories, but yours is probably totally sufficient in practice.

Comment: It's not at all uncommon for executables to be in non- bin/ directories.  Many packages have wrappers or symlinks in /bin or /usr/bin and executables somewhere under /usr/lib or /usr/share.   `mailman`, for example, has many executables under /usr/lib/mailman - most of them are intended to be executed by the mailman system itself rather than on the command line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ha, I already found it; it's `rpm -ql bind-utils` as Jeff Schaller noted in the comments.

A slightly more polished version that filters out non-executables from the list is:

`for file in $(rpm -ql packagename) ; do test -x $file && test -f $file && echo $file ; done`

Comment: `test -f` is redundant once you have `test -x` (which says "file exists -and- is executable)

Comment: Nope; I checked the manual and also tested it—`test -x` will return directories as well as files.

Comment: good catch -- packages do list directories, so your test is good

Answer (score 0):

Use below one liner command for listing a package's command:

```
 rpm -ql systemd | grep -w 'bin\|sbin' | awk -F '/' '{print $NF}' | xargs man head | grep ' - ' | grep -vi 'No manual' 2> /dev/null
```