# /lib/udev/findkeyboards missing

Tags: scripting, keyboard, udev, usb-device

I'm trying to follow the answer [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/88801) to set up some key swaps (<kbd>Capslock</kbd> as <kbd>CTRL</kbd>) on external keyboards (Microsoft Natural Ergonomic 4000).

First step is this. Get the details of your USB keyboard. Run this command with the keyboard plugged in:

```
$ /lib/udev/findkeyboards | grep USB
USB keyboard: input/event6
```

This doesn't work for me, as `/lib/udev/findkeyboards` doesn't exist on my system - from Googling I can't find anyone else with this issue! Any idea why not - and how I can acquire the right version?

I'm running Xubuntu 16.04 64-bit, using the i3 window manager.

`uname -a` gives me this:

```
Linux will-ThinkPad-X220 4.13.0-45-generic #50~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed May 30 11:18:27 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not finding `findkeyboards` in any packages on Ubuntu 16.04 either. I did locate it in the Git repo for udev, so perhaps it's no longer being packaged, would be my guess. `findkeyboards` is nothing more than a shell script so you can install it where ever you like. It's located here:

- https://github.com/lu-zero/udev/blob/master/src/keymap/findkeyboards

When I downloaded it and installed it, it appears to work fine:

```
$ ./findkeyboards
USB keyboard: input/event6
USB keyboard: input/event7
```

Comment: Right, that makes sense! Thank you for your help.